# Updating Variable from User Input

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, user-input, gspread

I am trying to make a program which the user enters contact information which is than stored in a Google Sheets document. The user enters their input, through the phrase:

```
def add_phone():
    contact_phone = input("Please enter the contact's phone number: ")
```

I use this to set the contact_phone variable, which is defined at the top of the document by `contact_phone = ''`. The problem is that when I try to send this information to the Google Sheets document

```
def store_info(contact_phone):
    worksheet.append_row(contact_phone)
```

It says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/contactList/main.py", line 46, in <module>
    add_contact()
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/contactList/main.py", line 19, in add_contact
    store_info()
TypeError: store_info() missing 7 required positional arguments: 'contact_fname', 'contact_lname', 'contact_phone', 'contact_email', 'contact_address', 'contact_birthday', and 'contact_notes'
```

As you can see I am using more variables than just `contact_phone` but the same problem applies with all variables used (contact_fname, contact_lname, etc.)
I was wondering if there was any way to update the variable from `''` to the inputted variable (phone number) before I reach this step, without stopping the code.

I have tried setting the variable to itself after the input is inputted by the user `(contact_phone = contact_phone)`, but I have had no success.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: @quamrana I just did. Thanks for the advice

Comment: In the `add_phone()` function the variable `contact_phone` is a local variable — you need to declare it `global` at the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. I started by defining global variables in my input functions: `global contact_phone` (as suggested by user: martineau).

This didn't fix all of my problems though. I had one function that had all the steps, including the input functions and my function which sends/saves the information to the Google Sheet document. I realized that the variables wouldn't update until the function finished so I removed the Google Sheets function (which read the inputted variables) from the main function and called it on its own after I called my main function:

```
add_contact()
store_info()
```

This lets the variables update to what the user inputted when the function would end. Then my next function (`store_info`) would be able to read the inputted variables and send these updated variables to the Google Sheet document, allowing them to be whatever is inputted by the user. **Thanks to everyone who contributed!**

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are 7 columns in the Google Spreadsheet.
You need to pass all 7 columns in the list.
e.g.

```
worksheet.append_row(['contact_fname', 'contact_lname', contact_phone, 'contact_email', 'contact_address', 'contact_birthday', 'contact_notes'])
```

Replace the actual values.

If you need to append only contact_phone, then first get the details in row list and append the row[3] = contact_phone.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. The problem is that I have variable's set at the top of my python file. Those variables are not updated from user-input until the my main function code stops. I am looking for a way to update those variables real-time without stopping my function/the code. I am able to put my variables into the Google Sheet, but I cannot update them so they change with the users inputs.